# about use of graphics(GUI)

Tags: c++, graphics

i know this is not a disscusion forum,but i am going to ask a question,whose appropriate answer was not given to me by anyone,
I am new to programming & learning C++,NOW,when i am doing  well with it,& was curious to learn graphics in C++,i came to hear that **the graphical programming in C++,is  difficult,& is not used commonly,as there are many other languages which can do all this much more easily as compared to C++.**

now my questions are:

1. the bold sentence is valid upto which extent
2. is it a good thing to start learning any other language to handle the graphics for me

Comment: Please be a little more specific about graphical programming. Do you mean Graphical User Interfaces (GUI) or 3D/2D Graphics?

Answer (score 2):

Graphics with C++, if you mean Graphical User Interface and Desktop programs, is ***really*** easy if you use, for example, [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/). Yes, C++ GUI isn't pleasant if you're not using any library and are using only the OS API (or a really old library such as MFC), but why would you do that?

I must admit though that the WYSIWYG editor integrated in Visual Studio for C# is a bit more intuitive than that of Qt Creator for C++. But that's a matter of habit and taste, I think. Writing desktop applications with Qt is piece of cake!

If by graphics you mean game dev with real 3D graphics, then I'm afraid it's not trivial in any language. You should probably have to learn OpenGL or Direct3D (OpenGL has C API, Direct X has C++ API)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably true that GUI programming in C++ is more difficult than in some other languages, unless you're an expert in C++ and dislike those other languages.

If you did want to do relatively common GUI things in C++, you might consider using the Qt library, which is mature and at least somewhat cross-platform (your apps will probably seem a bit ugly on Windows or Mac, but maybe not too bad).

As for other languages to learn, you should ask about that on programmers.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2):

As long as [most (PC and console) games are written in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722908/what-programming-language-is-used-for-video-games) I would not dare to say

> the graphical programming in C++,is difficult,& is not used commonly

Hard, yes, common? YES!

Other languages might make programming graphics easier but for sheer speed C++ is still a very valid option.

anti flame disclaimer: I know there are many languages/APIs that are quite capable of handling graphics.